# what points should I consider for very very high traffic website

Tags: php, frameworks, social-networking

I am creating a social networking site in PHP framework. I am thinking about points.

- Server technology
- Database and Indexing
- Caching (memory and database and file)
- Load balancing

Can somebody help me with points. What other points should I consider.

Comment: Code Comments, Code Comments, Code Comments.

Comment: I found very nice article about high traffic site points. we can use that article points. **here is link** http://digcms.com/2012/01/19/which-points-consider-if-you-want-to-create-high-traffic-site/. We need take care so many points when we are really thinking about very high traffic site. Keep in mind...Hardware is cheap...but good software and architectural hardware is not cheap....

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a prototype running
2. Write good maintainable code
3. Use common sense (like using PK and indexes in your DB of choice), don't join with views etc
4. Start with few users, see where the bottle necks are, and then decide/ask again.

Or, like the saying goes : "Premature optimization is evil" and here is [someone who disagree](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/09/06/ThePrematureOptimizationIsEvilMyth.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been written I would like to add that if your website is using database then it is highly recommended to use **database connection pooling** rather than opening/closing connection in each script for a high volume site.